# Ejecutar un cron en jenkins cada 14 días empezando desde el jueves

Tags: cron, jenkins

Me gustaría que el cron se ejecutase periódicamente cada 14 días empezando desde el jueves. Es decir, un jueves sí otro no.

Ahora mismo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

El cron se ejecuta cada semana

```
0 7 * * 4
```

Al llamar a mi función, mediante una variable en base de datos (true/false) habilito si accede a ella o no.

Me gustaría saber si existe la manera de hacerlo desde jenkins.

Un saludo,
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Definir "un jueves sí y otro no" directamente con crontab no es posible. Lo que puedes hacer es que dentro del script revises si es uno y otro, para salir sin hacer nada en la mitad de los casos.

Comment: @fedorqui Así lo tengo en estos momentos y obtengo el mismo resultado, pero como estuve mirando y no encontré nada con crontab, me picaba la curiosidad... Muchas Gracias

Comment: Puedes "jugar" con https://crontab.guru y ver opciones. Si fuera un día sí, otro no, sería posible. Pero opciones más complejas como la que comentas no son posibles (que yo sepa).

Comment: @fedorqui Sí! encontré esa web por casualidad y estuve trasteando y lo máximo que llegue fue, a que me ejecutase cada jueves que fuese par, creo recordar, pero con el cambio de mes, se podía dar el caso que se ejecutase dos jueves seguidos.

Comment: ¿Y algo como [https://crontab.guru/#0_7_1-7,15-21,29-31_*_4](https://crontab.guru/#0_7_1-7,15-21,29-31_*_4)? Le dices que debe ser en jueves y que el día del mes debe ser del 1 al 7, o bien del 15 al 21 o bien del 29 al 31.

Comment: @fedorqui Por lo que veo desde crontab, con eso que me estas diciendo, se ejecutaría todos los días a las siete.

Comment: Caramba, ¡es cierto! Leyendo en [Why crontab uses OR when both day of month and day of week specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34357126/1983854) lo confirman. Es _uno u otro_, cuando yo pensaba que era _uno y otro_.

Answer (score 0):

En Jenkins tenes que ir a el apartado "Disparadores de ejecucion". Posterior a eso marcar la casilla ejecutar periodicamente. Una vez ahi podes programar cada cuanto se va a ejecutar el job con el siguiente formato: MINUTO(0-59) HORA(0-23) DIA(1-31) MES(1-12) DIA DE LA SEMANA(0-7) 0 y 7 son el domingo.

En los lugares donde no queres especificar pondrias un asterisco(*)

Entonces para ejecutar todos los jueves una variante podria ser: 0 0 * * 04

En caso de querer hacerlo cada dos semanas, me guiaria por el dia segun el mes